# libav filter aformat not converting properly to new sample rate

Tags: libav

I made a test bench application to test LibAV's FilterGraph. I would like to use it (among other filters) to convert any given audio track to signed 16bit stereo PCM (`s16`) at 48kHz sample rate. Currently my test sound file is located here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Median_test.ogg
The conversion is fine when I take the files 44,100Hz sample rate and make [afromat](https://libav.org/documentation/libavfilter.html#aformat) return that exact sample rate. However, when attempting to convert to 48000Hz, there is noticeable popping.

Looking at the waveform generated, it appears to be rather crudely converting the audio file by spacing out the wave form over time and leaving the generated spaces with 0's.

To my knowledge, and the documentation, `aformat` should be creating `resample` as needed to handle this type of situation [as specified here](https://libav.org/documentation/libavfilter.html#resample).

The code I am using is shown below. Taking in `../test.ogg` and outputting `../out_filter.raw` as 16bit PCM @ 48000Hz.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

FILE *fh;

int read_packet(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buff_size) {
    return (int) fread(buf, 1, (size_t) buff_size, fh);
}

int perform_decoding() {
#define out_rate 48000
#define out_layout AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO
#define out_format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16

    AVFormatContext *ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    uint8_t *buffer = av_malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    AVIOContext *aioctx = avio_alloc_context(
            buffer,       // Buffer
            BUFFER_SIZE,  // Buffer size
            0,            // write_flag
            NULL,         // opaque
            read_packet,  // read_packet
            NULL,         // write_packet
            NULL          // seek
    );
    ctx->pb = aioctx;
    avformat_open_input(&ctx, "stream", NULL, NULL);
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(ctx, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Resampler has read the stream info.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int audio_stream_index = -1;
    AVStream *stream = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        stream = ctx->streams[i];
        if (stream->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audio_stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (audio_stream_index == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find the audio stream.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    AVCodecContext *cctx = stream->codec;
    AVCodecParameters *params = stream->codecpar;
#define in_rate params->sample_rate
#define in_layout params->channel_layout
#define in_format params->format

    AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(cctx->codec_id);
    if (codec == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (avcodec_open2(cctx, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: avcodec_open2()\n");
        return -1;
    }

    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);
    packet.data = NULL;
    packet.size = 0;

    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();

    FILE *out = fopen("../out_filter.raw", "wb");


    /// { FILTER
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph = NULL;
    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    if (!filter_graph) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "unable to create filter graph: out of memory\n");
        return -1;
    }

    AVFilterContext *abuffer_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *volume_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *aformat_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *abuffersink_ctx = NULL;
    const AVFilter *abuffer = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffer");
    const AVFilter *volume = avfilter_get_by_name("volume");
    const AVFilter *aformat = avfilter_get_by_name("aformat");
    const AVFilter *abuffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffersink");

    int err;
    char strbuf[512];
    // create abuffer filter
    AVCodecContext *avctx = cctx;
    AVRational time_base = cctx->time_base;
    snprintf(strbuf, sizeof(strbuf),
             "time_base=%d/%d:sample_rate=%d:sample_fmt=%s:channel_layout=0x%"
                     PRIx64,
             time_base.num, time_base.den, in_rate,
             av_get_sample_fmt_name(avctx->sample_fmt),
             avctx->channel_layout);
    fprintf(stderr, "abuffer: %s\n", strbuf);
    err = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&abuffer_ctx, abuffer,
                                       NULL, strbuf, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (err < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "error initializing abuffer filter\n");
        return err;
    }
    // create volume filter
    double vol = 0.2;
    snprintf(strbuf, sizeof(strbuf), "volume=%f", vol);
    fprintf(stderr, "volume: %s\n", strbuf);
    err = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&volume_ctx, volume, NULL, strbuf, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (err < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "error initializing volume filter\n");
        return err;
    }
    // create aformat filter
    snprintf(strbuf, sizeof(strbuf),
             "sample_fmts=%s:sample_rates=%d:channel_layouts=0x%" PRIx64,
             av_get_sample_fmt_name(out_format), out_rate, (uint64_t) out_layout);
    fprintf(stderr, "aformat: %s\n", strbuf);
    err = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&aformat_ctx, aformat, NULL, strbuf, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (err < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "unable to create aformat filter\n");
        return err;
    }
    // create abuffersink filter
    err = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&abuffersink_ctx, abuffersink, NULL, NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (err < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "unable to create aformat filter\n");
        return err;
    }

    // connect inputs and outputs
    if (err >= 0) err = avfilter_link(abuffer_ctx, 0, volume_ctx, 0);
    if (err >= 0) err = avfilter_link(volume_ctx, 0, aformat_ctx, 0);
    if (err >= 0) err = avfilter_link(aformat_ctx, 0, abuffersink_ctx, 0);
    if (err < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "error connecting filters\n");
        return err;
    }
    err = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "error configuring the filter graph\n");
        return err;
    }
    /// } FILTER

    while (av_read_frame(ctx, &packet) >= 0) { /// Fetch a packet
        if (packet.stream_index != audio_stream_index) {
            continue;
        }

        /// Decode packet to frame V1
        avcodec_send_packet(cctx, &packet); /// Toss the packet into the codec context
        av_frame_unref(frame);
        avcodec_receive_frame(cctx, frame); /// Pull out a frame
        if (frame->nb_samples == 0) {
            av_packet_unref(&packet);
            continue;
        }

        AVFrame *oframe = NULL;

        oframe = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!oframe) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "error allocating oframe\n");
            return 1;
        }

        /// Push the audio data from decoded frame into the filtergraph
        err = av_buffersrc_write_frame(abuffer_ctx, frame);
        if (err < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "error writing frame to buffersrc\n");
            return -1;
        }
        /// Pull filtered audio from the filtergraph
        for (;;) {
            err = av_buffersink_get_frame(abuffersink_ctx, oframe);
            if (err == AVERROR_EOF || err == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
                break;
            if (err < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "error reading buffer from buffersink\n");
                return -1;
            }
            int nb_channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(frame->channel_layout);
            int bytes_per_sample = av_get_bytes_per_sample(frame->format);
            int data_size = frame->nb_samples * nb_channels * bytes_per_sample;
            fwrite(oframe->data[0], 1, (size_t) data_size, out);
        }

        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();
    avfilter_register_all();

    fh = fopen("../test.ogg", "rb");
    if (fh == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open the file.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int ret = perform_decoding();
    if (ret != 0) {
        return ret;
    }
    printf("Finished!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet shown below mistakenly used the input frame to determine the bytes to copy out of the new converted frame. This chunk of code used the input frame called `frame` instead of the output frame called `oframe`.

```
int nb_channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(frame->channel_layout);
int bytes_per_sample = av_get_bytes_per_sample(frame->format);
int data_size = frame->nb_samples * nb_channels * bytes_per_sample;
fwrite(oframe->data[0], 1, (size_t) data_size, out);
```

The corrected version is shown below:

```
int nb_channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(oframe->channel_layout);
int bytes_per_sample = av_get_bytes_per_sample(oframe->format);
int data_size = oframe->nb_samples * nb_channels * bytes_per_sample;
fwrite(oframe->data[0], 1, (size_t) data_size, out);
```

The stuttering was caused by not copying the correct amount of bytes.